# Editing and deleting XML nodes with PHP

Tags: php, xml, editing

I've been looking around but still can't find a workable answer to editing and deleting xml with php without the use of simpleXML (how I wish i could use it). I was hoping someone could break it down simply for me, as my brain doesn't cope with this stuff! The xml file I have to work with looks something like this:

```
<allentries>
  <entry>
    <entryid>1</entryid>
    <title>This is the title</title>
    <date>2010</date>
    <author>Some Guy</author>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <entryid>2</entryid>
    <title>This is Another title</title>
    <date>2011</date>
    <author>Some Other Guy</author>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <entryid>3</entryid>
    <title>This is the other title</title>
    <date>2012</date>
    <author>And Another Guy</author>
  </entry>
</allentries>
```

I need to be able to do two things with PHP - Firstly I need to be able to accept values posted from a form, pick the correct entry based on the entryid number and modify each element within that entry with the new data. For eg. if entryid = 2, skip to the second entry and replace the text within title, date and author with the new data.

The second thing I need to be able to do (with a different function obviously) is pick the entry based on the entryid number and delete the whole entry, tag, data, children and all.

It sounds like it shouldn't be too hard, but every example I've used so far fails to do anything. Can anybody suggest anything or any other tutorials somewhere that may help me?

Thanks muchly for your time!

Comment: Can you please clarify why you cannot use SimpleXML and whether you can use any of the other [XML extensions available](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), preferably [DOM](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)?

Comment: i don't have access to change the xml file - I was under the impression that you need to add top/tail tags to make the xml read as a string to be usable with simplexml - any extensions that don't require me to change the xml file would be fine i think

Comment: I dont understand what you mean by adding top/tail tags. Do you mean you have to wrap the XML into a root element? That's only needed when your XML does not already have a root element. The XML you show does have one with `allentries`.

Comment: sorry Gordon, bear with me I'm a php noob lol - each example i see of using simpleXML to do what i need to do includes an xml file that is wrapped with "$xmlstr = <<<XML" at the start and "XML;" at the end because they use the simplexml_load_string function - can I get around this somehow?

Answer (score 0):

2 quick ways, both using regular expressions:

- break the XML to array using regular expressions, with the value of the entryid as key

  - on update just construct the new value and replace the value at the specified key
  - on delete just unset
- use regular expression to replace nodes

No idea on the performance for this two cases. I'll try and provide an regular expression to help you.

Gabriel

Comment: parsing XML using regex and deleting/replacing nodes is not advisable. in fact, it's dangerous!

Comment: @stillstanding it's not dangerous. It's just not practical and very error prone unless you put great effort into writing a decent parser (which doesnt pay off when parsers are readily available)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, did some further research and found a good example at [this site](http://www.fluidbyte.net/php-and-xml-using-simplexml) using:

```
$xml_file = "thefile.xml";
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file($xml_file)){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

`simplexml_load_file` instead of `simplexml_load_string` works like a charm now! No wonder you guys were confused - thanks for all your replies and for tolerating my noobishness!